# PHP Estimation Function

Tags: php, statistics, regression, standard-deviation

I am trying to calculate value $x in a number series based on an array of numbers (as $numbers).

Ex:

```
$numbers = array(1=>1000,2=>600,3=>500,4=>450,5=>425,6=>405,7=>400,8=>396);
function estimateNumber($x) {
  // function to estimate number $x in $numbers data set
}
```

What would be the most statistically accurate method?

Comment: By "estimate" do you mean predicting the next number in a series? Unless you can make some statements about what kind of series would be passed into your function, there's not much that can be done. The next number could be 50000 or it could be 393 and either prediction could be justified.

Comment: The next number cannot be higher or equal to the previous number.

The application of this algorithm is to help estimate unsubscribe rates for an email list on my gaming site and predict unsubscribe rates (and thusly percentages) certain dates in the future. The first to the second number is the largest difference, and the unsubscribe rate goes down quite heavily after the 3rd or 4th days. I did not do well in statistics so I am clueless here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're attempting to do is a large branch of mathematics called [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation). Claiming one way is more "statistically accurate" than the other will probably spark religious wars. It all depends on what kind of data you're trying to interpolate.

[Linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) will be the most straightforward.

Comment: and I dont think php can handle that kind of deep mathematical calculation. In the good ol days scientists use fortran for this, now there is Mathematica or Matlab.

Comment: It's actually quite possible in PHP, as it is in most languages. While languages and tools such as Matlab or R are specifically designed with language constructs for this type of activity, more generalised languages such as C or java or PHP are no less capable of performing the mathematics. PHPExcel, for eaxmple, has just such features built in as part of the package, written in pure PHP, in order to replicate Excel's features.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide if you want to fit a straight line or an n-th order polynomial. Maybe try some examples in Excel to give you an idea of which you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single "most statistically accurate method". It depends on what you are estimating as well as previously observed values. Going by your existing set of values, it seems to be exponentially decreasing, and as you can see, by the 7th and 8th values, it's already reached a point where it decreases only by 5 and 4 respectively. You can expect this to further reduce by 3, 2 and 1, after which it would become almost constant, only changing a little in the decimal places.

This would be a fair approximation:

```
...
7  => 400
8  => 396
9  => 393
10 => 391
11 => 390
12 and above => 389.xxx
```